# AP client mode DHCP

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp, wireless-access-point

i got a Netgear WN604 which i want to use in client mode to provide internet connection to multiple wired pcs and powerline extenders but i got troubles with DHCP ip assignment.

Let me explain:

The basic configuration works ok, i set it up the AP in client mode, i run the site survey, i log in to WiFi net succesfully.

The problem is the DHCP function, as long as i use a static IP, subnet, gateway and dns for clients connecting to the AP everything is ok, lan and internet too.

If I enable DHCP on any client it just can't obtain a valid ip and the AP gives me a random ( i think ) one like 169.254.6.13 instead of a 192.168.1.xxx .

I tried the AP on 2 different networks, so i'm excluding any particular router setting affecting the DHCP assignment.

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the only dhcp server on the network? It's common to run into ip conflicts or issues when you have multiple dhcp servers. I tend to prefer to have one machine (server or router) handle all ip assignments per network as it limits possible issues.

Comment: If you don't support your answer by facts and theory, its only a comment

Comment: Yes Alex, i'm keeping it simple for testing purposes. Just the dsl modem router wifi, the ap connected to it and some wired and WiFi clients.